# PHP: sending URL with space

Tags: php, url, get

$my_venue has data with space. For example= "nana nono". when I hoover to the link it gets cut off by the space. it works ok if there is no space.

```
<tr onmouseover="mouse_event(this, 'hlt');" onmouseout="mouse_event(this, '');">
    <?php
    $my_venue= $row['name'];

    echo "<td><a href= http://x.x.x.x:xx/JUNK/search_results.php?user-val=&venue-val=$my_venue&region-val=&lhversion-val=&releaseversion-val=&testtype-val=&api-val=&rate-val=&journaldate-val=&comments-val=&date-val=&record=%25>{$row['name']} </a></td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['region']} </td>";
```

Oh BTW, I need the space because I need to pass this info to the DB and in the DB the data does have the space

Comment: Try removing the spaces here `{$row['name']} </a>` and `['region']} </td>`, see what that does.

Comment: @Fred - Avoiding all characters that need encoding is a really convolute approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode) the values and quote the attribute. Especially the latter is something you should ALWAYS do. Browsers may be lenient with lack of encoding but a space in an unquoted argument will end it no matter what.

```
echo '<td><a href="http://x.x.x.x:xx/JUNK/search_results.php?user-val=&venue-val='.rawurlencode($my_venue).'&region-val=&lhversion-val=&releaseversion-val=&testtype-val=&api-val=&rate-val=&journaldate-val=&comments-val=&date-val=&record=%25">'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'</a></td>';
```

Oh, and in case `mouse_event()` adds a CSS class on hover: You can use the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class and do not need any JavaScript for this. Unless you need to support IE6 of course, but if that's the case your problem lies somewhere else anyway. :)

Comment: No! Why would he ever need that? The PHP interpreter will do that when parsing the query string. Just like you never need to un-escape data you escaped to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: TS: `Oh BTW, I need the space because I need to pass this info to the DB and in the DB the data does have the space`

Comment: He does not need the space in the HTML. When he receives the variable he will have the space again.

Comment: &venue-val='.rawurlencode($my_venue).'&region-val=   doesn't work. still cut off

Comment: Show the whole line, and please use backticks to format it as code.

Comment: `echo "<td><a href= http://x.x.x.x:xx/JUNK/search_results.php?user-val=&venue-val='.rawurlencode($my_venue).'&region-val=&xhversion-val=&releaseversion-val=&testtype-val=&api-val=&rate-val=&sournaldate-val=&comments-val=&date-val=&record=%25>{$row['name']} </a></td>";`

Comment: sorry I am new to PHP. what do yo mean by attribute? which one to quote? you mean `  $my_venue = "$my_venue";`

Comment: No! I'm talking about the href attribute in HTML. Simply copy&paste the line from my answer.. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_venue = str_replace(' ', '%20', $row['name'])
```

Comment: That won't fix any other characters that need special handling.

Comment: urlencode in php wil change it in a `+`. Where other languages change it in `%20`

Comment: @S.Visser - And `rawurlencode()` will change it to `%20`. You choose.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario thanks, did not know that. That should be an more clearer solution for the encode problem.